# Display data to chart .net framework

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Is there any other way to display the data, other than entering the data into the database and then merging it into the chart

I want to add this record field `Percentage.Text` to chart.

I have tried to put it in the list box

```
listBox1.Items.Add(num + ".  " + lbl_Time.Text + " =   " + Percentage.Text);
```

but I want to see how it looks on the chart.

Is there any other way, besides having to enter it into the database?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace battery_efficiency_meter
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void UpdateTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PowerStatus ps = SystemInformation.PowerStatus;

            PercentageBar.Value = (int)(ps.BatteryLifePercent * 100);

            if (ps.BatteryLifeRemaining < 0)
                TimeLabel.Text = "Charging";
            else
                TimeLabel.Text = "Remaining Time = " + new TimeSpan(0 , 0 , ps.BatteryLifeRemaining);

            Percentage.Text = string.Format($"{ps.BatteryLifePercent * 100} %");            
        }

        // Stopwatcch
        System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch stopwatch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();

        private void Start_But_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Stopwatch_Timer.Start();
            stopwatch.Start();
            //Start_But.Enabled= false;
        }

        private void Stopwatch_Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TimeSpan Lap = stopwatch.Elapsed;
            lbl_Time.Text = string.Format("{0:00} : {1:00} : {2:00} : {3:00}",
                Math.Floor(Lap.TotalHours), Lap.Minutes, Lap.Seconds, Lap.Milliseconds);
        }

        int num = 0;

        private void Lap_But_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            num += 1;
            listBox1.Items.Add(num + ".  " + lbl_Time.Text + " =   " + Percentage.Text);
        }

        private void Stop_But_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Stopwatch_Timer.Stop();
            stopwatch.Stop();
            //Start_But.Enabled= false;
        }

        private void Reset_But_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            stopwatch.Reset();
            lbl_Time.Text = "00 : 00 : 00 : 000";
            listBox1.Items.Clear();
            num = 0;
            //Start_But.Enabled= false;
        }
    }
}
```

[design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCHD9.png)

[when run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/of51R.png)

**Done I got it, Here the result**

```
int num = 0;
int num2 =+ 1;

private void Lap_But_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PowerStatus ps = SystemInformation.PowerStatus;
            //num +=1;
            listBox1.Items.Add(num2 + ".  " + lbl_Time.Text + " =   " + Percentage.Text);

            var batteryLifePercent = Convert.ToInt32(ps.BatteryLifePercent);            
            chart1.Series["battery"].Points.AddXY(num,ps.BatteryLifePercent * 100);
        }
```

maybe it will be a bit messy on the numbering in front of it, because I have changed a lot. But basically this line of code is what feeds the data to the graph, even though the windows system has to be called up again

```
chart1.Series["battery"].Points.AddXY(num, ps.BatteryLifePercent * 100);
```

[design result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6Oom.png)

Comment: To get data into an MSChart you can either use DataBindinding with or without a database. You wouls always bind to some IEnumerable. Or you can add the data with  Series.Points.AddXY calls. For binding note that there are several overloads; the usual way would bind not the chart but just one series.

Comment: @TaW  i have tried your suggestion `chart1.Series["battery"].Points.AddXY(num, Percentage.Text);` but the chart bar don't want to go out

Comment: this is the result [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1E5V_QtlfaxY3ESzKuUtwOCRGcngh4yWL?usp=share_link)

Comment: Better not add the y-values as strings. If possible those (as opposed to the x-values!!) will get converted to numbers, but relying on that is a bad idea. Add them as numbers and format the labels as you like..

Comment: @TaW i got it, ` Stopwatch_Timer.Start();
                stopwatch.Start();
                //
                PowerStatus ps = SystemInformation.PowerStatus;
                //int = ayam;
                listBox2.Items.Add(B++ + ".  " + lbl_Time.Text + " =   " + Percentage.Text);

                var batteryLifePercent = Convert.ToInt32(ps.BatteryLifePercent);
                **chart1.Series["battery"].Points.AddXY(num, ps.BatteryLifePercent * 100);**`